# Emoji changes my keyboard to its...

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, emoji

I have some problem. On start of my application I automatically show number pad keyboard(I send becomeFirstResponder to one of textfields) . But if user has used emoji keyboard before my application, emoji keyboard is shown. How can I avoid it? I want to show exactly number pad, but not emoji keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyboard notification and track the keyboard by using some BOOL variables,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

Check if a keyboard is already there by using the BOOL var. If its there resign it and show your keyboard.